# Mirror across 2 axis and only get two objects?

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier

I want an object mirrored across the x and y axis but I don't want 4 copies of it.
Is there a way to do this?

[image]

I have already tried rotating it around the center point using the array modifier but problems arise when I need to rotate the object relative to the center. Its copy doesn't rotate because it is bound to the empties transform.
[image]

I want to be able to modify it like a mirror.
[image]

Comment: You can try using an empty as a origin point, and rotating it

Comment: I need the origin of the rectangle to stay in the middle of the rectangle because I need to use it for other modifiers later. Can I set the origin to an empty just for one array modifier?

Answer (score 2):

It took me hours to figure out how to do this. But I figured it out.

Step 1: Place the object you want Rotated/Double mirrored at the location you want.

Step 2: Add an empty at the point that you want the rotation to take place.

Step 3: Add a mesh to the same coordinates as your empty. Then go into edit mode and delete all the vertices.

Step 4: Add a boolean modifier to your empty mesh and select your desired object as a unity target.

Step 5: Add an array modifier to your empty mesh and set the offset to be the empty you created in step 2.

Step 6: Rotate the empty to whatever angle you desire.

Bam you have a rotated copy but get to keep the origin of your original object.

[image]

It also works with as many as you want.
[image]